# Remove telephone field from Billing Information section in Magento

Tags: php, magento

How can I remove the `telephone field` from the **billing information section** in `magento`. But in **shipping information** I need `telephone field`. I can hide the telephone filed in `billing.phtml` file. But `telephone field` is `mandatory` field.So I can't click continue button.

I need  `telephone` field (as mandatory) in `shipping Information page`. And not need  `telephone` field in b`illing information page`.

How can I do this? Please help me...any help is really appreciable.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/configurable-checkout.html as I remember this module put inside your disabled fields some default value in background

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. If you have some code and it isn't working, post it so we can help solve your problem.

Comment: @ Mark Fitzgerald, I don't ask for code, but I need a suggestion or some help for how to do it. If I change something for one page(billing) it affects the other(shippig). Thats why I post the question here. The below link says for common case: http://swarminglabs.com/magento-making-the-telephone-field-not-required-at-checkout/

Answer (score 3):

The final solution contains three steps which are:

1. Remove client-side (javascript) validation
   If they not already exist within your theme copy the following files from the base/default theme to your theme:
   `template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`
   In each of these files, look for the  that defines the telephone field and remove the required class from the label, remove the required-attribute class from the input and make sure to remove the *.
2. Redefine the `Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract` class
   Copy the file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php to app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php . This ensures that upgrades will not break your modifications. Now open the file and look for the part where it validates the telephone field, it should look something like this:

   ```
   if (!Zend_Validate::is($this-&gt;getTelephone(), 'NotEmpty')) {
       $errors[] = $helper-&gt;__('Please enter the telephone number.');
   }
   ```

   You can either completely remove this part or comment it out by placing it between `/*` and `*/`.
3. Change the Customer EAV in the database
   Open the table `eav_attribute` and search for the row with `attribute_code = “telephone”`. Make note of the `attribute_id` of this row. Next, set the column `is_required` to `0` (zero).
   Now, open the table `customer_eav_attribute` and search for the row with the same `attribute_id` as you noted in the previous step. Set the column `validation_rules` on this row to NULL.

Comment: @ JIGNESH, this remove the validation of telephone in both billing and shipping page. I need to remove it only from billing page.

Comment: You can valid shipping telephone using magento classes on frontend. css class: input-text  required-entry

Answer (score 1):

```
app->code->core->mage->Eav->Model->Attribute->Data->Text.php
```

do not change in Database Table ………
you change in Text.php file .. i mentioned Path ....

change this:

```
if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && strlen($value) == 0)
{
   $errors[] = Mage::helper('eav')->__('"%s" is a required value.', $label);
}
```

to:

```
if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && strlen($value) == 0)
{
if($label != 'Telephone')
    {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('eav')->__('"%s" is a required value.', $label);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use GoMage LightCheckout extension, it is a one-page checkout solution with a lot of useful options, and one of those options is an ability to sort the fields or remove the ones you do not need. So, you could disable the phone number field using the admin panel settings of that extension.

Answer (score 0):

app->code->core->mage->Eav->Model->Attribute->Data->Text.php

do not change in Database Table ……… you can change in Text.php, please create a local copy for it, means core files editing is not a good practise in magento, so create a folder in app/code/local/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Text.php

change these lines:

```
if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && strlen($value) == 0)
{
   $errors[] = Mage::helper('eav')->__('"%s" is a required value.', $label);
}
```

to these:

```
if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && strlen($value) == 0)
{
if($label != 'Telephone')
    {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('eav')->__('"%s" is a required value.', $label);
    }
}
```

also

Change these lines :

```
$validateRules = $attribute->getValidateRules();        
                if (!empty($validateRules['min_text_length']) && $length < $validateRules['min_text_length']) {
                    $v = $validateRules['min_text_length'];
                    $errors[] = Mage::helper('eav')->__('"%s" length must be equal or greater than %s characters.', $label, $v);
                }
                if (!empty($validateRules['max_text_length']) && $length > $validateRules['max_text_length']) {
                    $v = $validateRules['max_text_length'];
                    $errors[] = Mage::helper('eav')->__('"%s" length must be equal or less than %s characters.', $label, $v);
                }
```

To :

```
$validateRules = $attribute->getValidateRules();
        if($label != 'Telephone')
            {
                if (!empty($validateRules['min_text_length']) && $length < $validateRules['min_text_length']) {
                    $v = $validateRules['min_text_length'];
                    $errors[] = Mage::helper('eav')->__('"%s" length must be equal or greater than %s characters.', $label, $v);
                }
                if (!empty($validateRules['max_text_length']) && $length > $validateRules['max_text_length']) {
                    $v = $validateRules['max_text_length'];
                    $errors[] = Mage::helper('eav')->__('"%s" length must be equal or less than %s characters.', $label, $v);
                }
            }
```